# Handling Incoming Parameters - Payment and Transaction with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an **Order** and an **OrderTransactions** model in my Rails4 application. They have a basic *has_one* and *belongs_to* relationship between them.

I'm posting requests from ***/orders/new*** page to the bank's URL as you can see below:

```
<%= simple_form_for(@order, :url => "https://testsanalpos.est.com.tr/servlet/est3Dgate", :method => :post) do |f| %>

  <% @hashing.each do |k, v| %>
    <%= f.input k, input_html: {name: k, value: v}, as: :hidden %>
  <% end %>

  <%= f.input :participation_id, ... %>
  <%= f.button :submit, "Ödeme Yap" %>
<% end %>
```

The @hashing, hash is coming from my controller =>

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!
  before_action :set_order, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token

  def new
    @order = Order.new
    @hashing = {
      clientid: POS['clientid'],
      oid: Time.now.to_i.to_s,
      amount: POS['amount'],
      okUrl: POS['okUrl'],
      failUrl: POS['failUrl'],
      rnd: Time.now.to_i.to_s,
     }
  end

  def create
    @order = Order.new(order_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      @order.purchase
    end
  end

  def success
  end

  def fail
  end

  private

  def set_order
    @order = Order.find(params[:id])
  end

  def order_params
    params.require(:order).permit(:id, :ip_address, :first_name, :last_name, :card_brand, :card_number, :card_verification, :card_expires_on, :user_id, :participation_id)
  end
end
```

**Order.rb =>**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :participation
  has_one :transaction, :class_name => "OrderTransaction"

  def purchase
    participation.update_attribute(:payment_status, true)
    create_transaction(:action => "purchase", :response => response)
  end
end
```

The bank's page is getting all necessary information from the user like credit card number, card expiration date etc. My application is not doing anything about purchase process, all of them are happening on the bank's side.

Then the bank is returning me a bunch of parameters about payment process. If the payment is success full, bank is posting the parameters to my /orders/success.html.erb and if it fails it is posting to /order/fail.html.erb.

**I have 2 problems =>**

1) I want the Order model instance is created whatever the response is successful or failed. It seems like that should be happening by create method in controller but it not working :/

2) How can I get the parameters that the bank send to my /fail or /success URL? I need to get them into my application and save them as a OrderTransaction instance in my database. I can see the parameters in my logs like this =>

```
Started POST "/orders/fail" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-06-01 13:40:28 +0300
Processing by OrdersController#fail as HTML
Parameters: 
  {
    "TRANID"=>"", 
    "Faturafirma"=>"OMÜ Uzaktan Eğitim Merkezi", 
    "islemtipi"=>"Auth", 
    "refreshtime"=>"5", 
    "lang"=>"tr", 
    "amount"=>"30", 
    "ACQBIN"=>"490740", 
    "clientIp"=>"193.140.28.145", 
    "name"=>"AKBANK", 
    "cardHolderName"=>"dsadas dasdsa", 
    "okUrl"=>"http://localhost:3000/orders/success",
    "storetype"=>"3d_pay_hosting",
    "Response"=>"Declined"
    ....
  }
```

**DB Schema =>**

```
create_table "orders", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "participation_id"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end

create_table "order_transactions", force: true do |t|
  t.integer  "order_id"
  t.string   "clientip"
  t.string   "cardholdername"
  t.string   "response"
  t.string   "errmsg"
  ...
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

**Routes.rb =>**

```
...
post 'orders/success' => 'orders#success'
post 'orders/fail' => 'orders#fail'
resources :orders, only: [:index, :new, :create]
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest:
Move your creation success failure into a model and pass it such.

```
 def success
   Order.create_from_params(order_params)
  end

  def fail
   Order.create_from_params(order_params)
  end
```

Then handle success failure from params using response Decline etc..

```
class Order<ActivewRecord::Base

def self.create_from_params(order_params)
  self.create(inflatewithfields) && self.purchase if params[response'] == 'success'

  self.create(inflatewithfields) if params[response'] == 'Decline'

end
end
```

Comment: I couldn't understand "self.create(inflatewithfields) && self.purchase if params[response] == 'success'" part, can you give an example?